# react.js, handleChange firing off before submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a simple form where the user enters in a number (only) and and then a function runs some math, update the state and return the number.

Currently, `handleChange` is firing off before I hit submit.

I know this code is early and has some issues, any help would be appreciated!

```
    class Container extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      age: 44,
      wookieage: this.getWookieYears(),
      helloworld: 'hello world',
      value: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.getWookieYears = this.getWookieYears.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    const newValue = event.target.value * 280;
    this.setState({ value: newValue });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  getWookieYears() {
    return ages * 7;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ContainLeft
        style={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100%',
          margin: 0,
          marginTop: '5em',
          padding: 0,
          justifyContent: 'center'
        }}
      >
        <Row style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <div>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <label>
                    Name:
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={this.state.value}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                  </label>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>

              </Col>

            </Row>
          </div>
        </Row>

      </ContainLeft>
    );
  }
}
export default Container;
```

Comment: it's not firing early. It's firing `onChange` of the `input` as you told it to.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code. `onChange` gets fired as you type. `onSubmit` gets called when submitting the form.

Comment: so do I move onChange on submit?  (this is where I get confused)

Comment: ah, I just realized I need to put my math in the onsubmit